# What happens when an object using ARC contains multiple non-ARC objects?

Tags: ios, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I have a class A which uses ARC and other classes B and C which don't. If A contains class B objects and B contains class C objects then how does ARC work and what happens when memory management is not handled properly in class B and C?

Comment: Everything just works. ARC isn't anything magic, it's just the compiler inserting retain/release for you. It can integrate just fine with non-ARC code.

Comment: Since class A has ARC so it will release the object which you have created.It will not release the object which have retain cycle, and class B and class c does not have arc so you have to manually release all the object which you have created.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Mike and Martin, that the integration of non-ARC objects in an ARC class generally takes place seamlessly (assuming you've added the `-fno-objc-arc` compile flag to those .m files that are not ARC or are in a library that was compiled with manual reference counting).

One caveat is that ARC relies upon code conforming with the method naming rules outlined in the [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1). Thus, your non-ARC code must comply with these method naming rules or else ARC may not handle the resulting objects correctly. This is not an issue if the non-ARC code follows long-standing method naming conventions (that methods starting with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, and `mutableCopy` will return +1 objects, and otherwise objects returned from methods will be `autorelease` objects), so it is generally not an issue. But if your non-ARC code does not follow this method naming convention, but it may become a memory management stumbling block when integrating this non-ARC code with your ARC class.

If the non-ARC code does not comply with these naming conventions, you either have to rename the methods, correct the memory management of the code to correspond to the method name, or supply hints for the compiler where the code does not comply with these method naming rules (e.g. `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` or `NS_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED`).

Answer (score 1):

What ARC does is it looks at your code and makes assumptions where your objects should be released, autorelease etc. At the compile time all the retain, release, retainCount, autorelease, or dealloc methods will be added to your code. This makes your non-arc code completely compatible with your arc code.

As for the improper memory management, try to use static analyzer on build to get as much errors as you can.

Hope this helps, cheers!

Comment: Those "assumptions" base on the ownership naming conventions described in the ["Basic Memory Management Rules"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-SW1), therefore it is important that the *non-ARC* code strictly adheres to these conventions. But you are right that the Static Analyzer will check that.

Comment: @MartinR Agreed, though the static analyzer doesn't find (all) failures to conform to naming conventions in non-ARC code. It does a remarkable job, but some failures only manifest themselves as leaks in Instruments.